# What are the technical challenges to store electricity from lightning strikes?

Tags: capacitor, theory

I ask myself that question every time I watch a Tesla documentary.  So, let's get some answers down so the smart ones can think about it and we can clean-up our environment.  There is free electricity all around us for crying out loud ;)

If the question is too broad, then here is my simplified idea based on my limited electrical/electronics naval training which can be critiqued:

Erect a, possibly very tall, tower completely grounded to earth.  Connect one terminal of a possibly very large capacitor to the tower.  A current detection circuit is connected to the tower-to-earth circuit which, upon a lightening strike, switches the current from flowing to ground to flowing to the capacitor and charging it.  After the current ceases, the current detector switches back to ground the tower.  Then, draw current from the capacitor as needed.

Comment: There are numerous problems with this approach. For start, where would you get a suitable capacitor? Then there's the design of the connection to the capacitor itself so that it can not only survive the strike but also not dissipate much energy, so that the most of it is stored in the capacitor. Long-term storage of electricity is problematic and there are basically almost no very efficient solutions, so power from the charged capacitor would have to be used up very quickly.

Comment: And that's not even getting into the logistics of lightning-as-power-source.  How would one ensure a regular enough occurrence of lightning to make it reliable?

Comment: Why are you answering in the comment section?  Try to reformat into bullet points in the answer section, such as, -Need a large capacitor rated at roughly X farads, etc..  Thx.  BTW, imagine a capacitor made of a large bed of sand as the semiconductor layer on top of another bed of conductive material of some sort.  Try not to be distracted by the scale of the challenges.

Comment: semiconductor -> dielectric

Comment: You just need to find a **capacitor** that can store **hundreds of millions of volts** without self-discharging and can charge at a **rate of a billion amps per second** without losing energy through heating the conductors you're using to  put the charge in place. ***Once you have such a capacitor, the remaining technical details are trivial.***

Comment: @Adam, thanks, but I'm at a loss as to why you didn't put those words in the answer section instead of the comments.

Comment: @AlJo because the question is a duplicate and as such it would be inappropriate for me to answer it creating more duplication. Your comments seem to suggest, however, that you are still unsure, so I provided a simple summary as a comment.

Comment: @Adam, that makes absolutely no sense and one of your premises is incorrect.

Comment: @AlJo I disagree that my comment is senseless, but having been in Stack Exchange since the beginning and watched it evolve over time I suspect I have a different perspective on answering duplicate questions than many who now use these sites. However I suspect there is little value for either of us to explore this disagreement further.  I do hope you found the information provided useful, and wish you luck in whatever endeavor you're involved with that brought you to this question!

Comment: I understand.  The hope is that this question withers and dies since it is a duplicate and so answering in the answer section would somehow work against that.  I get it ;)

Answer (score 10):

I'd argue the challenge isn't technical, it's economical. A normal lightning strike transfers about 500 megajoules of energy ([says Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Cloud_to_ground_.28CG.29)). Wikipedia also says [a single wind turbine comes as big as 7.5 megawatts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_power#Electrical_power) these days. Thus, a single bolt of lightning is equivalent to running a big wind turbine for:

$$ \frac{500MJ}{7.5MW} \approx 67 \text{ seconds} $$

That's also assuming that all the energy from the lightning is electrical and that you can get at all of it. You can't: most of that 500 MJ of energy is spent heating the air and Earth. If you want to get all of that energy, you will need to make the lighting do work on something that isn't the air, which means very tall towers. All told, there just isn't that much energy in lightning.

If the economic problem weren't there, your approach is basically sound. We already engineer skyscrapers to withstand lightning strikes without damage. The problem is in storing the energy. I'm sure something could be conceived with superconductors, or *really big* supercapacitors.

Trouble is it's cheaper to put up a wind turbine, or better, dig some rocks out of the ground and burn them.

Comment: Phil, the question is about the electrical power that is transferred to the earth and an electrical circuit to capture it, not the heat in the air.  So, I don't know why you start off talking about total energy in a lightening bolt.  Then, you say there is an economic problem without telling us what it is.  So, your answer is more of a comment or musing.  That's ok, I knew this Q was a risky one to ask.

Comment: @AlJo: The point that Phil is trying to make is that even if you could convert lightning to electricity with 100% efficiency, it would be uneconomical compared to a wind turbine. By 'economical problem' we mean simply that you get more electricity per dollar by building a wind turbine vs. a lightning tower. The part about the lightning energy being wasted as heat is just *further emphasising* the uneconomical nature of harvesting electricity from lightning.

Comment: @Li-aungYip, the heat produced in the air by the lightening is not part of the question so it is not considered a loss.  And yes, I understand what he is saying; I can read.  I'm asking for a little detail on the economics.  And, why do you say, "we mean..."?  Did you assist Phil in formulating his answer in some way?  I see no edits by you.

Comment: @AlJo: Economics: Calculate the number of lightning strikes/annum intercepted by a lightning tower, multiplied by the energy storage per strike. (Hint: lightning frequency can be expressed as a "Keraunic level"; there are not many lightning strikes per km².) Then, compare this to a wind turbine installation with equivalent energy output. The wind turbine is likely to be orders of magnitude more cost effective than the lightning tower. Feel free to prove this to yourself by rough calculations.

Comment: @AlJo the heat in the air is about the electrical energy: it's where it goes. If you let it heat the air, then there's no energy left to run lightbulbs. It's like trying to generate electricity by filling buckets at the outlet of a hydroelectric dam: sure, there's water, but all the energy has been removed from it.